# How to read data from excel from a particular column in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet and I am reading the excel sheet using pandas in python.

Now I want to read the excel file based on a column, if the column has some value then do not read that row, if the column is empty than read that and store the values in a list.

Here is a screenshot

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BE1Zx.png)

Now in the above image when the uniqueidentifier is yes then it should not read that value, but if it is empty then it should start reading from that value.

How to do that using python and how to get index so that after I have performed some function that I am again able to write to that blank unique identifier column saying that row has been read

Comment: What are your concerns regarding reading the whole file and then applying this logic? Is it too big for memory?

Comment: @roganjosh No sorry since I a newbie to python, I do not know how to do that efficiently. Right now I have the following logic df = df[df.uniqueidentifier != "yes"], but no way of writing to the column once that has been read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible for csv files. There you could do

```
iter_csv = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', iterator=True, chunksize=100000)
df = pd.concat([chunk[chunk['UniqueIdentifier'] == 'True'] for chunk in iter_csv])
```

But `pd.read_excel` does not offer to return an iterator object, maybe some other excel-readers can. But I don't no which ones. Nevertheless you could export your excel file as csv and use the solution for csv files.